# Why is my raise to power code running without doing anything?

Tags: python

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    i = 1
    base_num = float(input("Your base number= "))
    pow_num = float(input("Your Power number = "))
    if pow_num == 0:
        print(result)
    else:
        while i <= pow_num:
            result = result * base_num
            i += 1
    print(result)
```

When I run the code it's not even asking for an input, any ideas why?

I played with the indents changed the positioning of the code but that only furthers my problem. I don't know why it's not even asking for the input.

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: the function should either take the parameters as arguments or ask for them with `input()`. It shouldn't do both.

Comment: If you call the function I can't see any reason why it wouldn't ask for input.

Comment: @Barmar how do I call the function and how do i give them a value without input()?

Comment: Take out the `float(input(...` lines, and call `raise_to_power(3, 5)`

Comment: Alright, I'll try that and some other things as well, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def raise_to_power` defines the function for later use. By defining functions you can reuse the code inside the function, in case you need it in multiple places in your script.
Defining a function does not execute it. To execute the function you have to call it. In python (and most other languages) you can do this like this:
`raise_to_power()`

Since your function takes 2 parameters (base_num and pow_num) you have to give the function those. Instead of calling

```py
    base_num = float(input("Your base number= "))
    pow_num = float(input("Your Power number = "))
```

inside the function, you can request the input outside the function and then give those values to the function call as arguments:

```py
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    i = 1
    if pow_num == 0:
        print(result)
    else:
        while i <= pow_num:
            result = result * base_num
            i += 1
    print(result)

base_num = float(input("Your base number= "))
pow_num = float(input("Your Power number = "))

raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num) # Here we actually call (or execute) the function.
```

Comment: I see now what @Barmar meant too, appreciate the help and thanks a lot.

Comment: Just as the calls to `input` should be outside the function, so should the calls to `print`. *Return* the result with `return result`, and let the caller print the value if they need to.